# Mounting local network shares

Tags: networking, mount, cifs

I would like to request some advice on mounting local network shares.
1. When using the files GUI I can access the local network share. So I know the path and username and password is correct.

However whenever I try to mount it via CLI using the following command I get a request to enter the password

```
sudo mount.cifs //nas.local/video/movies /home/Plex/Movies username:xxxx,password=xxxx
```

(I have removed the username and password for obvious reasons and replaced with xxxx)

I get the following error when I enter password

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I have also tried the following in FSTAB

```
//nas.local/video/movies /home/Plex/Movies cifs rw username:xxxx password:xxxx 0 0
```

When I run `sudo mount-a` I get the following error

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 14.
```

Answer (score 1):

As I read your `/etc/fstab` line; its format is wrong in my opinion.  Maybe try

```
//ip.addr/sharename  /pathname cifs credentials=/path/filename 0 0
```

where you can put `username=blah` & `password=bleh` in a file (permissions for privacy but root needs read access to work, user needs read if they are to mount without sudo) wherever you like.

The username, password you used may work if you put a comma & not a space (space means the end of options & next field, so your password was invalid, see `man fstab`).

I don't refer to mine by ip.addr, but use device-names (`/etc/hosts` or my dns.cache interpret to local addr). I also mount (by command) differently to you but I rarely use CIFS or Samba except for backups which are by script thus mounted/umounted without my invention.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was trying to go simple to figure out the issue so thought to include the username and password in the FSTAB would be easier. Get that working and then move onto a credentials file. I have updated my fstab as follows, but still not working (//192.168.1.15/video/movies /home/Plex/Movies cifs rw username:xxxx,password:xxxx 0 0)

Comment: again spaces ... `rw,username=,password=`     my example didn't include rw as i accepted the default.   a space is the end of that operand meaning your username,password would have been where it expected a 0-.....

Comment: OK, so have changed it up again. Now I have **//192.168.1.15/video/movies /home/Plex/Movies cifs,rw,username:xxxx,password:xxxx 0 0
** do i need to have any other , in place?

Comment: And I get this error when running the mount -a Password for root@//192.168.1.15/video/movies:  ******
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: sorry.  have a look at the `man` pages; to me at least they are clear.  the type (cifs) is a different param to your options, and you need a space to delimit it & options.  rw,user=,password,auto,user,... are all optional params for the same list of options; thus need comma separation and not spaces  (ps: space=white.space; so can be tab, space ..)

Comment: very rough rule -- everything is space (device, path, type, (lots of options separated by comma), freq, pass..)  - but often there are lots of options (which need ',' to seperate so they aren't ready as the next field frequency..)  most fields have only single value; except options (rw,user,username=,password=,...)

Comment: I seem to be lost here. I have read through the Man and cannot really find the information I need. All I need to do is to get a few shares from my NAS shared on the Linux device.

Comment: device:/path(fs-spec)  local-path(fs-file)  type(fs_vfstype)  options  (fs_mntops)  freqnum(fs_freq)  passnum(fs_passno)  - with all seperated by whitespace (space/tab/..).  the cifs goes in the virtual.filesystem.type or type field, the rw,user,auto,username=..,password=..,... are all fs.mount.options thus are not white.spaced except before & after them; they are comma separated.  you're getting lost in my attempt to explain what is wrong.  cifs is a type & has to be whitespace seperated from rw|ro,username,password,user,auto&other-options-used  (user = users can mount without needing sudo)

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. I think i have the syntax correct, as it seems to want to mount. However I get asked for the root password for the share. I am 100% sure on the password as I can use it to mount it via the GUI.  Why would I recieve permission deined.

Comment: check the obvious things; if its your user account doing the mounting - do you have read/write (assuming its 'rw' permission) to the folder; or did you create the folder with "sudo mkdir /wherever" and thus 'root' has rw permissions but not you (or the reverse; try making mount.dir 777 (rwx for everyone) once)...   (i've never mounted from gui; so have no idea how it achieves a mount...)    ...  new thought: try mounting to /mnt; or a created directory (/movies maybe) instead of /home/blah..